# Error : argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run the below Shiny App but I am getting a:

> "ERROR: argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default"

message. Even though I take care of the mainPanel inside the sidebarLayout and outside the sidebarPanel and I tried another relative solutions available on the web, but the error remains the same.

Please help me in finding the error and rectifying it.

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  titlePanel("Road Accident"),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(selectInput('geo', 'Country', choices = list("Unknown" ="AT","BE","CZ","DE","DK","EL","ES","FI","FR",
                                                "IE","IT","LI","LU","NL","PT","RO","SE","UK","PL","SI","BG","CH","CY",
                                                "EE","HU","IS","LV","MT","NO","SK","HR","LT")
                             )
                 ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("newHist"))

  )
))


library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(eurostat)

p1<-get_eurostat("tsdtr420",time_format="num")
p2<-p1[!rowSums(is.na(p1)),]

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {


    output$newHist<- renderPlot({
       p3 <- filter(p2, grepl(input$geo,geo))
     p<-ggplot(data=p3,aes(time,values))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none")+
       labs(title="Road Accidents",x="",y="Victims")
       print(p)

      output$geo
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do it without `sidebarLayout`, it works fine. You just need to check the required arguments of your elements with `?pageWithSidebar`, `?sidebarLayout` and so on... `pageWithSidebar` requires three arguments, you were only giving two.

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  titlePanel("Road Accident"),
  sidebarPanel(selectInput('geo', 'Country', choices = list("Unknown" ="AT","BE","CZ","DE","DK","EL","ES","FI","FR",
                                                              "IE","IT","LI","LU","NL","PT","RO","SE","UK","PL","SI","BG","CH","CY",
                                                              "EE","HU","IS","LV","MT","NO","SK","HR","LT"))),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("newHist")))
)
```